# robotium nullPointerexception

Tags: android, robotium

I setup a test project to test another Android project. Everything is working fine. I can call solo.clickOnView and the test will run fine. Problem happens when i try to update a view, for example, i want to update an EditText by calling solo.enterText.

Robotium version
3.6

```
String hello="Hello world"
solo.enterText(myEditText, hello);
```

I'm sure that myEditText is a non-null object. Run the test and the below message will come

## Error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Instrumentation.runOnMainSync(Instrumentation.java:338)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.TextEnterer.setEditText(TextEnterer.java:52)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.enterText(Solo.java:1404)
at com.darakok.test.TestMain.testDisplayBlackBox(TestMain.java:30)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

Comment: of course it's not null. I can call solo.clickOnView() and it works fine.

Comment: It gives the impression that i can read from the UI, but not able to modify the UI.

Comment: Can you paste in your whole test file?

Comment: I've found my problem. I need to initialise solo object like this: new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

Comment: "of course it's not null. I can call solo.clickOnView() and it works fine." that couldn't of been true then?

Answer (score 0):

See API docs, this method works only with index of an element. So if you want to use id:

```
String hello="Hello world";
solo.typeText(myEditText, hello);
```

Comment: By documentation, ** enterText() ** works with "android.widget.EditText" and "index"

Comment: Too old answer, maybe

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps myEditText isn't actually assigned towards the right EditText?

```
String hello = "Hello world";    

//Based on the ID of the EditText you've given via the layout XML: 
EditText myEditText = (EditText) tester.getView(R.id.my_edit_text);
solo.enterText(myEditText, hello);
```

Another possible reason for this occuring is when the `myEditText` block being executed before the entire Activity (or even just the EditText itself) has loaded properly. In those cases, I suggest `assertCurrentActivity(), sleep() or waitForView()`

Answer (score 0):

you might not have initialized the object.
Just make sure that the objects which you are using have been  **initialized**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do an extra check before execute your code:

```
solo.enterText(myEditText, hello);  // your code
```

you can write the follow snapcode:

```
ArrayList<View> views = solo.getViews();
for (View view : views) {
    // check if your view is on the views arraylist, use a break point o whatever
}
```

Maybe when you try to modify your view, it is not attached on layout or maybe it is not editable.